# Is it possible to get the iOS 6 advertisingIdentifier in Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get the iOS 6 [`advertisingIdentifier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html) in Mobile Safari?

Comment: As in you want your web page to have access to that value when visited by an iDevice using mobile safari?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot currently be done.

From http://oleb.net/:

> iOS apps can read the state of this preference and are required to respect it (see below). I would have loved if Mobile Safari also used this setting to send an appropriate Do Not Track HTTP header but unfortunately that is not (yet?) the case.

Here's the link:

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/